# Instantaneous validation of form field length

Tags: javascript, validation, comparative-review, form, dom

Since I have a function which can be done in few ways as usual, I was wondering which way is the best to achieve the form validation where I have only one input field, and I am showing a warning on keyup if the number of characters are in between 1 and 3 as well as enabling disabling submit button based on number of characters. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VHhQF/40/). So I have two functions:

```
var myFunction = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var warning = document.getElementById("warning");
    var button = document.getElementById("button");

    if (input.value.length >= 1 && input.value.length <= 3){
        warning.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else {
        warning.style.display = 'none';
    }

    if(input.value.length > 3){
        button.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        button.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Here I have two if else statements, so I was wondering what would be the cleanest way to achieve the same thing? The only thing I could come up with was this function:

```
var alternative = function () {
    var input = document.getElementById("input");
    var warning = document.getElementById("warning");
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    warning.style.display = 'none';
    button.disabled = true;

    if (input.value.length >= 1 && input.value.length <= 3)
        warning.style.display = 'block';

    if(input.value.length > 3)
        button.disabled = false;
}
```

But I am not sure what is the best approach performance wise, since in the second function I have states that will always be the same on calling the function and then changing them based on conditions and in the first one I first check the conditions and then manipulate the elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Ternary operator**

You could use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for your first if-else case:

`warning.style.display = input.value.length >= 1 && input.value.length <= 3 ? 'block' : 'none';`

Now, this is a bit lengthy so we might choose to store `input.value.length` inside another variable like so:

```
var length = input.value.length;
warning.style.display = length >= 1 && length <= 3 ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Note, that if you can use ES6 features you could benefit from using `const` and [object matching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and declare length as follows:

`const { length } = input.value;`

**Direct assignment**

As for your second scenario, you could store the conditional directly inside your variable since you just want the negated version of what you're checking:

`button.disabled = length <= 3;`

**A more general code review**

The comparison against `1` and `3` is very vague and they are considered [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). What do these variables represent?

You could incorporate another self explaining variable, such as `isWarning` as follows:

```
// ES5
var length = input.value.length;
var isWarning = length >= 1 && length <= 3;

// ES6
const { length } = input.value;
const isWarning = length >= 1 && length <= 3;

warning.style.display = isWarning ? 'block' : 'none';
button.disabled = length <= 3;
```

This helps the structure, but still doesn't answer the question of what do the values `1` and `3` represent?

I'm assuming you aren't checking `0` since you don't want a warning to show on an empty input, so I'll provide an example of what could be done:

```
// For ES5 change const to var
const minLength = 4; 

const isEmpty = length === 0;
const isValidLength = length >= minLength;
const isWarning = !isValidLength && !isEmpty;

warning.style.display = isWarning ? 'block' : 'none';
button.disabled = !isValidLength;
```

Note, that `minLength` would ideally have a more descriptive name related to what it is checking. `minNameLength`, `minPostcodeLength`, etc. This way the code reads relating to the logic it's checking, now how that logic is implemented each time.

**Misc - ES6 deep object matching**

If you are using ES6 you could use [deep object matching](http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingDeepMatching) to get `length` directly:

`const { value: { length } } = document.getElementById('input');`

This is useful since we are only concerned with the input's length, not the element itself.

**Misc - Consistent use of quotes**

Another small remark is your use of quotes. Either is fine but it's best to be consistent - you're using double quotes in `getElementById` but single quotes for setting `display`.

I'll continue to add things when I have time. If you have any questions/concerns please leave a comment.